# How to set this height of collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

[image: image - 1]

[image: image - 2]

Here in "image-1" you can see that the Blue colour CollectionView1 and the red colour is CollectionView2 by default i gave the height of the CollectionView1 - 115...as it shows....but when I debug it (pic in "image2") it shows its height as 184....i need to add a left and bottom anchor since its height is not correct I cant proceed it

Answer (score 0):

Please check attribute of your both collection view cells and for example you can use

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{

        if collectionView == YourCollectionView1 {
           return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width/2 - 1, 196)
            }
        }else {
            return CGSizeMake(90, 90)
        }
    }
```